# WMI Issue - The paging file is too small for this operation to complete

Tags: windows, wmi

I have an issue with a Windows Server 2008 Standard SP1 whereby I have lost the ability to monitor it remotely. After investigation, it appears to be because there is an issue with WMI. In the WMI COntrol Properties, it states:

```
Failed to initialize all required WMI classes.
Win32_Processor: Win32: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
```

The page file seems fine 2314M / 12404M. I have tried restarting WMI with no positive result.

After searching, I found this article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981314) which indicated that there was a hotfix for this issue, but after trying to install it, I get this error :

```
The update does not apply to your system.
```

I'm sure that a reboot will cure the issue (from what I have read) but this will cause me issues and it is likely to re-occur again if not fixed properly.

Has anyone had a similar experience and/or any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: "The page file seems fine 2314M / 12404M." What does that mean?  You have 2313 MB of memory, and the page file is 12,404 MB?  How much memory does the system have, and what is the size of the pagefile?

Comment: Hi Greg, I took that from Task Manager. The system has 6GB of RAM. Under 'Virtual Memory' I have: 'Recommended' : 9198MB and 'Currently Allocated' : 6432MB. Thank you.

Comment: Is the pagefile being managed by the system or are you manually specifying the pagefile size?

Comment: @joeqwerty It's managed by the system

Comment: You state your server is 2008 standard, the technet article and hot fix are for 2008 r2. Hope that explains your error when attempting to apply the hotfix.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your WMI files have been corrupted, try running `winmgmt /verifyrepository` or 
 WMIdiag http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7684

If these show errors rebuild the repository